# always getting failure in Ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am always getting failure as the message, but the functions are executed succesfully. this is my ajax call.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>?q=search/newfunc",
                datatype: 'json',
                data:{id:id ,data1 : data1},
                 success: function (returnval) {
                    alert("success");
                    var col=[];
                    $('#mTable').find('td').each(function(index, cell){
                        col.push($(this).attr("class"));//
                    }); 
                    var id = (col[0].match(/\d+/)); 
                    $('table#mTable #dataid').html(newdata);

                },// end of function success
                error: function(returnval) {
                    alert("Failure"+id);
                }
```

The function which is handling the above is this ;

```
function search_newfunc()
{
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $data1 = $_REQUEST['data1'];
    echo $num_updated = db_update('mtable')
    ->fields(array(
        'db_data1' => $data1,
    ))
    ->condition('id',$id, '=')
    ->execute();
    if($num_updated)
    {
        return "Sucessfn";
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failurefn";
        die();
    }
```

}

Comment: Don't return in backend try `echo`.

Comment: you are calling q=search/newfunc but your function is search_newfunc()

Comment: Can you show us the resulting HTML / Javascript Code from the Php inline code?

Comment: @Abhi : thanks, for finding that.. Actually , it is called in drupal module. so a page callback has been made there to  search_newfunc()

Comment: i tried with removing the datatype:json, still getting "failure" only.

Comment: @RononDex : iam not clear , can u please help me

Comment: are you getting failure in alert or as a reponse?

Comment: @Manwal : did u checked the echo i had written as 'echo $num_updated ="

Comment: @Abhi : As alert.. when i checked the response in the browser , i saw a 1 there with some more things...

Comment: `1[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bartik","theme_token":"-lyeEnOgS4b5uPL4MK0tiro9bjqlcrkkqCD7ukrLd2E"}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":null,"selector":null,"data":"Sucessfn","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"","settings":null}] `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not echo the variable `$num_updated`,

and replace ,

`return "Sucessfn";` with `echo  "Sucessfn";`

`return "Failurefn";` with `echo  "Failurefn";`

Comment: @EthanHunt The problem was your server wasn't returning valid JSON because of the former `1` in response due to `echo $num_updated` i guess

Comment: but, now i removed that json, and still now it works.

Comment: Well, the ajax call reads the response from the server, and that response must be rendered as some type of readable data, such as application/json or text/html.

In order to write that data, you need to echo it from the server with PHP.

The return statement doesn't write data, it simply returns at the server level.

Comment: hey , that solved.. one issue in the succes call here..can i ask u @Abhi

Comment: `$('table#mTable #dataid').html(newdata);`   this line is making the content of my table into a input editable box, how to make it readonly

Comment: you can use `readonly` parameter of input box  like `<input type="text" name="country" value="something" readonly>`

Comment: but how to apply it in td.. and iam just putting new data to that td using the .html()

Comment: @Ethan Hunt can I know what value your getting in newdata

Comment: Please provide the detail of the #mTable #dataid